# How to filter/split a large list based on specific column values?

Tags: apex, map, list, set

I have a list with 50 thousand records. Want to filter those records base on **Branch** name column values. **In the list Branch==>Temp has 3 records and  Temp2,Temp3,Temp4==>has respectively 1 record**. I need to send a mail with each chunk, Mail send is not my problem, I need help with how to chunk them base on Branch value.

[image]

Comment: Can you detail what you've tried so far and where are you stuck? Not sure if it fills your requirement, but querying those records and grouping them by Branch__c should do the trick.

Comment: @user1067017 thanks for your reply, how to group the list? after group, how to filter the base list. So far I know the where clause is absent in the list data structure. how to filter?

Comment: after the `GROUP BY Branch` you will get just one line for temp, temp2, ... So what else you want to filter there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you're describing, it sounds less like sorting and more like you're trying to put records into buckets. Apex does not have a built-in way to do this, so it's up to us to write the requisite logic.

Assuming you're working with an SObject, it shouldn't be too much of a leap to see that a `Map<String, List<MySObject__c>>` is what you're looking for. For each key value (Branch__c), you store a list of records (where each record's Branch__c is equal to the key)

Some example logic to get you headed in the right direction

```java
Map<String, List<Account>> accountsByCity = new Map<String, List<Account>>();

for(Account acct :accountsToProcess){
    // An elegant way to build a map like this is to check to see if the map we're
    //   building does NOT contain our target key.
    // If that is the case, we add the key to the map (and put an empty list as the value)
    // This makes it so that the rest of the logic is the same no matter if it's the first,
    //   50th, or 14729th item we're putting into the map

    if(!accountsByCity.containsKey(acct.MailingCity)){
        accountsByCity.put(acct.MailingCity, new List<Account>());
    }

    accountsByCity.get(acct.MailingCity).add(acct);
}

// Accessing the records in each bucket generally means you'll be looping over the map's keyset
for(String key :accountsByCity.keySet()){
    system.debug(accountsByCity.get(key).size() + ' Account(s) for City ' + key);

    // If you need to do something with each individual account in a given bucket, a nested
    //   loop is required
    for(Account bucketAccount :accountsByCity.get(key)){
        system.debug('Account in bucket ' + key + ': ' + bucketAccount);
    }
}
```